# Can we put a Heatsink on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, hardware

how bout RAM Heatsinks, separate item, is it possible, although have not seen one, but is it small enough to fit? viable? since im torrenting 24/7 (well not really 24/7)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can put a heatsink on top of the CPU, but as you can see in the picture below, the CPU isn't the hottest part of the board.

[image: Thermal Image of the RPi]

The network chip is the hottest part of the RPi. The [site](http://www.raspberry-pi-case.com/) where I borrowed this image sells casings that include a heat sink. If you want to use separate heat sinks, you only need a good way to fix them properly on top of the chips (at least for the time is takes adhesive thermal paste to dry).

I guess the 'sandwich' method the referenced website uses for the casing is a very good option, you got your heatsink and a casing in one.

Comment: didnt know that it was the network chip... thanks for the answer

Comment: I would discourage tinkerers from buying this case, as the screws make GPIO cables hard to plug/unplug. Also it's conductive exterior might be detrimental in a workshop setting in which it could come into contact with various power supplies. +1 for build quality though

Answer (score 1):

I'm not affiliated with the provider of this in any way apart from being a customer. I've bought two sets of these ([Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Quality-Heatsink-set-raspberry-model/dp/B00C97MLPO/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1368040743&sr=8-2), [ModMyPi](https://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi-heat-sink-kit), [Farnell equivalent](http://uk.farnell.com/multicomp/pi-heatsink-kit/heatsink-kit-for-raspberry-pi/dp/2319947) (not identical model)) for two Pis and they work pretty well. Pretty easy to fix into place with provided thermal tape (although you need to cut it to size yourself).

The set includes 3 heatsinks for the three areas highlighted above.

Comment: In case that link breaks, could you add the make/model/description of that item?

Comment: I'm afraid they don't have a make or model. The exact item description is "Quality Heatsink set for the raspberry Pi model A and B from New IT". If the link does break I believe they are available from other suppliers so I'll have a look and add some more links to the article (and then people can remove dead links if they happen)

Answer (score 1):

There are many heatsink "kits" available on eBay for ~$5. They usually contain:

- A heatsink for the main chip (the RAM and SoC underneath it)
- A heatsink for the USB Ethernet Chip (usually the hottest part)
- A heatsink for the Voltage regulator
- 3 heat conductive adhesive pads that make for an easy way to secure the heatsinks on whilst still allowing heat to transfer through.