# OpenELEC and Kodi 24/7

Tags: sd-card, openelec, media

I've already read [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/325/is-the-raspberry-pi-suitable-for-running-continuously-24-7).

However, they are mainly talking about using Raspberry as a server. 
I was wondering if it is OK to run Raspberry Pi B+ permanently 24/7 doing slideshows (picture+video), reading from the sdcard. Does it heat and reboot? Which considerations should I talk care about?

System Stats:

- I'm running OpenELEC 5.0 with the lastest included Kodi build.
- Images ~4MB, Videos (about 1m or less) ~100MB. Should I tweak cache settings?
- TV display is 60''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving the Pi running 24/7 is generally not a problem. Reading the SD card will not wear it out. (Writing to the SD card will wear it out over time, should not be an issue for this application). Just go for it, it's not very expensive after all. I would worry much more about the power consumption and wear of the TV.

You can [monitor the CPU temperature](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/357/how-do-i-monitor-and-or-control-the-temperature-of-the-soc), but it doesn't really get hot (unless you overclock). Anyway, the [network chip runs hotter](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4333/can-we-put-a-heatsink-on-the-raspberry-pi) than the CPU.

I have had xbmc/kodi running nearly constantly on one of mine for about a year, with no problems. To be fair, most of the time it didn't actually play videos / slideshows, but my feeling is that this does not matter.

Comment: What is more stable? : run permanently or restart Kodi every day?

Comment: @redraw, I tend to leave it on, and only restart after I've updated the package.

Answer (score 0):

If it is videos only, you can try creating a playlist of videos and playing them in loop.

If you want to include pictures and videos then you may need to write a script accordingly(need to go through Kodi documentation for developers). I just want to give you a heads up on the idea and I am not sure whether it is possible. All the best.

Comment: Hey, thanks but that's solved in Pictures. I'm doing Slideshow and it works as expected. It can mix pictures and video inside `/storage/pictures`. My question is if it's ok to let Raspberry Pi B+ running 24/7

Comment: Glad it worked. As long as the temperature and other external parameters are good, I don't think there will be any problems.